# Apache/GnuTLS: can't get multiple TLS-enabled virtual hosts to work

Tags: apache-2.2, namevirtualhost, gnutls

A while ago, I set up an SSL certificate authority for our intranet, generated a bunch of certificates and ran a number of sites with them, all on the same physical host with one single Apache2 installation; one root certificate and one certificate for each virtual host. I added the root certificate to the client machines and everything was fine (i.e. all communication was protected).

Now I am trying to switch from `mod_ssl` to `mod_gnutls`. Changes to the Apache2 configuration were simple:

- disable the SSL module: `a2dismod ssl`
- enable the GnuTLS module: `a2enmod gnutls`
- add a new section to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` with the same contents as the SSL section:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
  </IfModule>
  ```
- change per-site configurations in e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.domain-ssl`:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_gnutls.c> 
    <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerAdmin  webmaster@site1.domain
      ServerName   site1.domain
      DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.domain_ssl/public_html/
      ErrorLog     /var/www/site1.domain_ssl/logs/error.log
      CustomLog    /var/www/site1.domain_ssl/logs/access.log combined
      LogLevel     debug

      # <Directory ... > settings omitted

      # old SSL configuration:
      # SSLEngine on
      # SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/site1.cert.pem
      # SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/site1.key.pem

      # new TLS configuration
      GnuTLSEnable on
      GnuTLSPriorities NORMAL:!DHE-RSA:!DHE-DSS:!AES-256-CBC:%COMPAT
      GnuTLSCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/site1.domain.cert
      GnuTLSKeyFile         /etc/ssl/private/site1.domain.key
    </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
  ```

I re-created the cetificate authority root certificate from scratch, created new per-site certificates and re-deployed them. (I used to use .pem file suffix with SSL, but dropped that when switching to GnuTLS).

**The problem** is now that I can not access any virtual hosts.

When I try to connect to the physical host, everything seems fine:

```
user@host:~$ gnutls-cli-debug host
Resolving 'host'...
Connecting to '127.0.1.1:443'...
Checking for SSL 3.0 support... yes
Checking whether %COMPAT is required... no
Checking for TLS 1.0 support... yes
Checking for TLS 1.1 support... yes
  ... (etc.) ...
```

and when I connect using `gnutls-cli --x509cafile <my root cert file>`, the root certificate is validated successfully.

However, when I try to connect to one of the virtual hosts, this happens:

```
user@host:~$ gnutls-cli-debug site1
Resolving 'site1'...
Connecting to '192.168.137.135:443'...
Checking for SSL 3.0 support...|<1>| Received record packet of unknown type 60
 no
Checking whether %COMPAT is required...|<1>| Received record packet of unknown type 60
 yes
Checking for TLS 1.0 support...|<1>| Received record packet of unknown type 60
 no
Checking for TLS 1.1 support...|<1>| Received record packet of unknown type 60
 no
  ... (etc.) ...
```

and I get error message like these in the Apache log:

```
[Mon May 19 17:55:35 2014] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] GnuTLS: Handshake Failed (-21) 'Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite.'
[Mon May 19 17:55:35 2014] [info] (70014)End of file found: GnuTLS: Error reading data. (-9) 'A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.'
[Mon May 19 17:59:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.137.135] Invalid method in request \x16\x03
```

Of course there are plenty of Google results about these errors, but despite spending pretty much the entire weekend searching, nothing conclusive has come up.

This is all taking place under a fresh installation of the latest Debian 7.5 i386 on a VM (which I've set up to find the error, the actual intranet server is a real machine), so Apache does [support SNI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2):

```
user@host:~$ aptitude show apache2-mpm-worker | grep Version
Version: 2.2.22-13+deb7u1
user@host:~$ aptitude show libapache2-mod-gnutls | grep Version
Version: 0.5.10-1.1
```

The [mod-gnutls](https://mod.gnutls.org/) page explicitely states that it supports Server Name Indication, but to me, it looks like this is simply not the case.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: can you show configuration of a `vhost` ?

Comment: I've updated the question with a full site configuration showing the old SSL and the new TLS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several discussions with `dkg` in `#mod_gnutls` on `irc.indymedia.org`, it turned out that the [default version 0.5.10-1.1](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libapache2-mod-gnutls) of `mod-gnutls` in the latest Debian 7.5 (package name `libapache2-mod-gnutls`) simply does not support SNI properly - quote from the chat:

> quite a lot of bugs around SNI were fixed in the latest 0.6 version

AFAICT, version 0.6 is scheduled for Debian 8 (which will be released when it's finished ;-) and there don't seem to be any backports. One workaround is to build `mod-gnutls` and its dependency `GnuTLS` from the sources; some pointers to get started [here](https://mod.gnutls.org/wiki/develop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508851/217844).